# libspatialindex and Rtree on python

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, python-3.x, spatial-index, r-tree

Okay, so I am trying to install `libspatialspatialindex` to my Ubuntu machine python. I did follow all the instructions and downloaded `libspatialindex1_1.4.0-1.1_amd64.deb` from http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libspatialindex1 and downloaded the amd64 version of it as my machine is 64bits machine. I installed it and then jumped to Rtree python https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree to download and install the Rtree in python. I followed the installation instruction given in the install.txt file inside the folder. It says run the local setup.py by `$ python setup.py install` I did that as well but what I get after that is

```
`root@ubuntu:/# cd /home/neelabh/Desktop/Rtree
root@ubuntu:/home/neelabh/Desktop/Rtree# python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
import rtree
File "/home/neelabh/Desktop/Rtree/rtree/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .index import Rtree
File "/home/neelabh/Desktop/Rtree/rtree/index.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import core
File "/home/neelabh/Desktop/Rtree/rtree/core.py", line 110, in <module>
rt.Error_GetLastErrorNum.restype = ctypes.c_int
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
func = self.__getitem__(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: python: undefined symbol: Error_GetLastErrorNum`
```

Can somebody please help me in resolving this issue!

I really appreciate in advance!

Comment: Using the wrong directories maybe?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have to install the package "libspatialindex-dev" with the systems package manager. At least this is true with my system (Mint 17.1) which should be 100% compatible to a default Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Thanks. There were couple of more libraries that were missing. But the issue got resolved.

Comment: This worked for me and should probably be the accepted answer!

Comment: Works for ubuntu 18.04 also. Thanks friend.

Comment: Also solves the problem on ubuntu 20.04. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `libspatialindex-dev` in your ubuntu system. Here i am using ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install libspatialindex-dev`

install Rtree using your python pip version, i have pip 3.7

`pip3.7 install Rtree`

`import rtree`