# Overly Function from GeoPandas Not Working

Tags: python, pandas, gis, geopandas

I simply want to use `geopandas` to get a union and intersection of two polygonal areas. I define:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
polys1 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2,2), (0,2)]),
                                  Polygon([(2,2), (4,2), (4,4), (2,4)])])
polys2 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(1,1), (3,1), (3,3), (1,3)]),
                                  Polygon([(3,3), (5,3), (5,5), (3,5)])])

df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys1, 'df1':[1,2]})
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys2, 'df2':[1,2]})
```

I try the following to get the `union`:

```
res_union = gpd.overlay(df1, df2, how='union')
```

and it fails with the following ERROR:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'intersection'
```

I am following the instructions [here](http://geopandas.org/set_operations.html).

Comment: I also get a warning complaining about missing package `rtree`, even though I have that installed.

Comment: UPDATE: It goes fine in my local machine when my geopandas is 0.3.0, not in my cloud env in which I have geopandas 0.4.0.

Comment: Your example above works fine for me on both geopandas 0.3.0 and 0.4.0. You get the error with the above example? Can you show the full error traceback?

Comment: I installed `rtree` package and it fixed the issue. `conda install rtree`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Despite I don't know the OP's operational system I think that I figured out how to solve the problem, at least for GNU/Linux systems (I'm not able to test in other systems).

**Direct explanation**

To be able to use the `overlay` function you need more than just install `geopandas`, you need install `rtree`, but `rtree` is a wrapper to the C library [libspatialindex](https://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex). So to use `rtree` library you need to install `libspatialindex` C library.

To install `libspatialindex` open a terminal end type:

`sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y libspatialindex-dev`

Note: actually you only need the `sudo apt-get install libspatialindex-dev`, but it is good practice update the system, and the -y flag is just to don't stop the installation process to ask for continue with the installation or not.

Now it should solve your problem. Note: make sure you have `rtree` installed in your system, you can do this using `pip3 freeze` (I am supposing that you use `python3`).

**Long explanation**

I faced the same error, and spent a lot of time to figure out what was the problem. The answer to this question [libspatialindex and Rtree on python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28491322) give to me a tip on how to solve the problem.

Consider the bellow code (the OP's code example) and save named as `script.py`:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon


polys1 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2,2), (0,2)]),
                        Polygon([(2,2), (4,2), (4,4), (2,4)])])

polys2 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(1,1), (3,1), (3,3), (1,3)]),
                        Polygon([(3,3), (5,3), (5,5), (3,5)])])

df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys1, 'df1':[1,2]})

df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys2, 'df2':[1,2]})

res_union = gpd.overlay(df1, df2, how='union')
```

Consider the following `requirements.txt`:

```
Shapely==1.6.4.post2
descartes==1.1.0
geopandas==0.4.0
matplotlib==3.0.2
```

If you try to only install the libraries in the `requirements.txt` and run `scrip.py`, and not install `rtree` library according to the `requirements.txt`, it is going to show the following error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/base.py:76: UserWarning: Cannot generate spatial index: Missing package `rtree`.
  warn("Cannot generate spatial index: Missing package `rtree`.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 17, in <module>
    res_union = gpd.overlay(df1, df2, how='union')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/tools/overlay.py", line 371, in overlay
    result = _overlay_union(df1, df2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/tools/overlay.py", line 298, in _overlay_union
    dfinter = _overlay_intersection(df1, df2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/tools/overlay.py", line 212, in _overlay_intersection
    sidx = bbox.apply(lambda x: list(spatial_index.intersection(x)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 3194, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1472, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/tools/overlay.py", line 212, in <lambda>
    sidx = bbox.apply(lambda x: list(spatial_index.intersection(x)))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'intersection'
```

The last line of the error message

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'intersection'`

is not so useful. But if you look to the first line:

`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/base.py:76: UserWarning: Cannot generate spatial index: Missing package`rtree`.`

it is complaining about the `rtree` library.

So lets install `rtree` and see what happens. `requirements.txt` now is updated to:

```
Shapely==1.6.4.post2
descartes==1.1.0
geopandas==0.4.0
matplotlib==3.0.2
rtree==0.8.3
```

Runing again the `script.py` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 3, in <module>
    import geopandas as gpd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/geoseries.py", line 12, in <module>
    from geopandas.base import GeoPandasBase, _series_unary_op, _CoordinateIndexer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/base.py", line 14, in <module>
    from rtree.core import RTreeError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rtree/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .index import Rtree
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rtree/index.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rtree/core.py", line 125, in <module>
    raise OSError("Could not find libspatialindex_c library file")
OSError: Could not find libspatialindex_c library file
```

The last line complain about `libspatialindex_c`, so as explained in the first part of my answer, the "Direct explanation", just run the bellow code to install `libspatialindex` and the `script.py` should work.

`sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y libspatialindex-dev`

At least for me the problem is solved.

Comment: For arch user: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/spatialindex/
and pip install rtree

Answer (score 1):

Geopandas documentation tells what follows:

*For historical reasons, the overlay method is also available as a top-level function overlay(). It is recommended to use the method as the function may be deprecated in the future*.

For that reason, I'd do it this way:

`df1.union(df2)`