# Error using geopandas overlay with union method

Tags: python, overlay, geopandas

---

### (I manged to solve this by installing anaconda and installing geopandas in a new environment)

My original problem:

I have several polygons stacked on top of each other and I'm trying to use the geopandas overlay with union method to get all those possible geometries returned.

I did not get it to work so I tried the example code directly, ref. https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/set_operations.html:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas

polys1 = geopandas.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2,2), (0,2)]),
                              Polygon([(2,2), (4,2), (4,4), (2,4)])])


polys2 = geopandas.GeoSeries([Polygon([(1,1), (3,1), (3,3), (1,3)]),
                              Polygon([(3,3), (5,3), (5,5), (3,5)])])


df1 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys1, 'df1':[1,2]})

df2 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys2, 'df2':[1,2]})

ax = df1.plot(color='red');

df2.plot(ax=ax, color='green', alpha=0.5);

res_union = df1.overlay(df2, how='union')

res_union
```

But i get the following error:

```
IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

I have tried all the other methods as well: ['intersection', 'union', 'identity', 'symmetric_difference', 'difference'] but the only ones that are working are the 'intersection' and 'difference '.

------- Addedd 08.03.2022 -------
This is the full path from the error which is thrown

> ```
> IntCastingNaNError                        Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_19804/2462211871.py in
> ```
>
> ----> 1 geopandas.overlay(df1, df2, how='union')
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\overlay.py
> in overlay(df1, df2, how, keep_geom_type, make_valid)
> 319             result = _overlay_symmetric_diff(df1, df2)
> 320         elif how == "union":
> --> 321             result = _overlay_union(df1, df2)
> 322         elif how == "identity":
> 323             dfunion = _overlay_union(df1, df2)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\overlay.py
> in _overlay_union(df1, df2)
> 135     """
> 136     dfinter = _overlay_intersection(df1, df2)
> --> 137     dfsym = _overlay_symmetric_diff(df1, df2)
> 138     dfunion = pd.concat([dfinter, dfsym], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
> 139     # keep geometry column last
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\overlay.py
> in _overlay_symmetric_diff(df1, df2)
> 115     _ensure_geometry_column(dfdiff2)
> 116     # combine both 'difference' dataframes
> --> 117     dfsym = dfdiff1.merge(
> 118         dfdiff2, on=["__idx1", "__idx2"], how="outer", suffixes=("_1", "_2")
> 119     )
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py
> in merge(self, *args, **kwargs)    1376     1377         """
> -> 1378         result = DataFrame.merge(self, *args, **kwargs)    1379         geo_col = self._geometry_column_name    1380         if
> isinstance(result, DataFrame) and geo_col in result:
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
> in merge(self, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index,
> right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)    9189
> from pandas.core.reshape.merge import merge    9190
> -> 9191         return merge(    9192             self,    9193             right,
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py
> in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index,
> right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
> 118         validate=validate,
> 119     )
> --> 120     return op.get_result()
> 121
> 122
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py
> in get_result(self)
> 734             result = self._indicator_post_merge(result)
> 735
> --> 736         self._maybe_add_join_keys(result, left_indexer, right_indexer)
> 737
> 738         self._maybe_restore_index_levels(result)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py
> in _maybe_add_join_keys(self, result, left_indexer, right_indexer)
> 915
> 916                 if result._is_label_reference(name):
> --> 917                     result[name] = Series(
> 918                         key_col, dtype=result_dtype, index=result.index
> 919                     )
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py
> in **init**(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
> 381                 if dtype is not None:
> 382                     # astype copies
> --> 383                     data = data.astype(dtype)
> 384                 else:
> 385                     # GH#24096 we need to ensure the index remains immutable
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\numeric.py
> in astype(self, dtype, copy)
> 221                 # TODO(jreback); this can change once we have an EA Index type
> 222                 # GH 13149
> --> 223                 arr = astype_nansafe(self._values, dtype=dtype)
> 224                 return Int64Index(arr, name=self.name)
> 225
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py
> in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)    1166     1167     elif
> np.issubdtype(arr.dtype, np.floating) and np.issubdtype(dtype,
> np.integer):
> -> 1168         return astype_float_to_int_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy)    1169     1170     elif is_object_dtype(arr):
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py
> in astype_float_to_int_nansafe(values, dtype, copy)    1211     """
> 1212     if not np.isfinite(values).all():
> -> 1213         raise IntCastingNaNError(    1214             "Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer"    1215         )
>
> IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to
> integer

Comment: this post may help you，https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546775/overly-function-from-geopandas-not-working，  df1.union(df2) works

Comment: df1.union(df2) works but give me one union, and not all possible geometries as the overlay with how="union" method would have given me.  I have read the post, but I don't find a solution to my problem. I have installed Rtree, but when it comes to libspatialindex, I'm not sure exactly what to do.

Answer (score 0):

code has no problem checkout your geopandas version by :

```
import geopandas as gpd
gpd.__version__
```

if it was not 0.10.2 update it

Comment: I checked and my geopandas version is 0.10.2.