# AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'overlay'

Tags: overlay, geopandas, r-tree, libspatialindex

I get an odd error when I run this overlay intersection using geopandas:

```
grid = grid.overlay(national_outline, how='intersection')
```

The error states no attribute 'overlay' is available despite both `grid` and `national_outline` being functioning geopandas dataframes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eoughton\Desktop\Github\ccdr-basic\scripts\wealth.py", line 238, in <module>
    create_regional_grid(country)
  File "C:\Users\eoughton\Desktop\Github\ccdr-basic\scripts\wealth.py", line 62, in create_regional_grid
    grid = grid.overlay(national_outline, how='intersection')
  File "C:\Users\eoughton\Anaconda3\envs\ga\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5575, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'overlay'
```

I've only found one other similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546775/overly-function-from-geopandas-not-working) which identified libspatialindex and rtree as potential culprits.

However, I've exported my conda environment from another computer where this works fine, and created it on a new machine which produces this error. Both libspatialindex and rtree are installed. The .yml environment file with all package versions is [here](https://github.com/edwardoughton/satellite-image-analysis/blob/main/sia.yml).

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: The `overlay` method was only added in GeoPandas version 0.10.0, maybe you have an older version? (you can check `geopandas.__version__`) On older versions, you can use the function instead: `grid = geopandas.overlay(grid, national_outline, ..)`

Comment: Thanks, Joris. This actually worked when I changed the function specification to the one you state. Do you want to add it as a proper answer and I will then be able to fully close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `overlay` method was only added in GeoPandas version 0.10.0, so based on the error, you probably have an older version (you can check `geopandas.__version__`).

On older versions, you can use the function instead:

```py
grid = geopandas.overlay(grid, national_outline, ..)
```