# Installing "libspatialindex-dev" on Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas

I am trying to conduct an inner spatial join using Geopandas, where both `points` and `poly` are Geodataframes.

```
instersection = gpd.sjoin(points, poly, how='inner')
```

However it is throwing up the error of:
`` Spatial indexes require either `rtree` or `pygeos` ``

I am aware it is do with not having installed `libspatialindex-dev` (see [libspatialindex and Rtree on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491322/libspatialindex-and-rtree-on-python)), but none of the `sudo apt install ...`  method works on Jupyter.

How am I able to install it on Jupyter notebook?

Comment: you can install geopandas, jupyter, and rtree at the same time with conda in a way that will ensure they're all set up to work together. see this guide on installation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72251100/3888719

Comment: note that using conda to install these compiled dependencies does not require you to be root, as they will be installed within your conda dir.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Colab notebook you can find this link to be helpful:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1N7i9zmOwVcUzd4eHWZux4p_WTBMZHi8C

I ran the above notebook and was able to successfully install rtree.

While this may be helpful as well:

On your Jupyter cell run this:

```
!apt-get install -y libspatialindex-dev
```

Comment: I tried running your version of ```apt-get``` but is throwing me errors saying ```E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?```

Comment: You do not have permission.. may be you need admin rights.. please check.